# ReactJS | Check if a user exists from match.params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, error-handling, promise

I am trying to check if a user exists, from the URL match.params. Basically, I want to redirect the user to a 404 Page, if the URL:
`/user/username`, does not exists.

I want to check if that parameter, exists in my list of users which comes from the API.

Here is the code, that works but I know for a fact, it is wrong. Don't know why it works. I am at it since yesterday, and can't make it work. Please help.

**Component Code:**

```
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.shape({
      isExact: PropTypes.bool,
      params: PropTypes.object,
      path: PropTypes.string,
      url: PropTypes.string
    }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
    history: PropTypes.object,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    actualValue: PropTypes.string,
    callBack: PropTypes.func
  };

  state = {
    user: {},
    error: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUser();
  }

  getUserUsername = () => {
    const { match } = this.props;
    const { params } = match;
    return params.username;
  };

  fetchUser = () => {
    getUser(this.getUserUsername()).then(username => {
      this.setState({
        user: username.data
      }).catch(({ message = 'Could not retrieve data from server.' }) => {
        this.setState({ // catch statement return undefined.
          user: null,
          error: message
        });
      });
    });
  };

  validateUsername = username => // This one is undefined
    listUsers().then(({ data }) => { // Data are coming just fine
      debugger;
      if (data.includes(username)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
```

Basically, the whole error validation of the page is screwed. I am in need of help. Here is the code for the `listUsers()` and `getUser()` services that call an endpoint and return a promise themselves.

```
export const listUsers = () => {
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.GET,
    url: endpoint.LIST_USERS
  };
  return instance(options);
};

export const getUser = username => {
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.GET,
    url: endpoint.GET_USER(username)
  };
  return instance(options);
};
```

I get this error for the catch statement: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined at Object.then.username`.

After a few more tries, I did this, and it seems to work, but still not sure:

```
  validateUsername = () =>
    listUsers().then(({ data }) => {
      debugger;
      const { match } = this.props;
      console.log(data, 'data');
      console.log(match, 'match');
      if (data.includes(match.params.username)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

*Catch* should be after *then* closing parentheses, not after the *setState* parentheses, for starters Δημήτρη!:

```
fetchUser = () => {
  getUser(this.getUserUsername())
    .then(username => {
      this.setState({
        user: username.data
      });
    })
    .catch(({ message = "Could not retrieve data from server." }) => {
      this.setState({
        // catch statement return undefined.
        user: null,
        error: message
      });
    });
};
```